# Redirect from old domain to new domain not work

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to Redirect from old domain to new domain, By below code, but not work, Where is error.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place redirect rule before WP catch-all rule otherwise you will only get `index.php` after redirect on new domain:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```